# PayPal API Error - Senders Email Is Not Confirmed

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the CreateSinglePayout.php sample code provided by paypal and I have my client id and secret set in bootstrap.php however no matter what I do I keep getting the error - Error: ACCOUNT_UNCONFIRMED_EMAIL - Sender's email is not confirmed.

The email on my paypal account IS INFACT CONFIRMED so I don't understand what's happening and I can't find any solutions anywhere.

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I wanted to add here.  I saw this error today being returned for an Unverified account, which is different than an unconfirmed email address.  I am following up to get this error mapping resolved; however, if you do see this error also ensure your account is verified.  In the US this usually involves confirming a Bank Account.

Answer (score 0):

Please file a support ticket with our [Merchant Technical Support](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask) team so that they can grab logs for your attempt.  When filing the ticket please make sure to include the debug ID from the error response as well as the date/time of the attempt.